# Splitting timespan and creating new fields in csv

Tags: c#, csv, ssis, split

The following csv structure and data is given:

```
timespan,someOtherField, ...
27.03.2017 - 31.03.2017,someOtherValue, ...
31.03.2017,someOtherValue, ...
```

I would like to split up the timespan into begin and end. As you can see a timespan can be several days (first record) or only one day (second record). Splitting up the first record is pretty easy by replacing the delimiter but i don't know how to process the second record. There must be some logic to identify it as single day (begin and end should be same value).

All is done in SSIS but i would like to realize it in C#.

Result:

```
begin,end,someOtherField, ...
27.03.2017,31.03.2017,someOtherValue, ...
31.03.2017,31.03.2017,someOtherValue, ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First add a Derived Column Transformation. Inside of the Derived Column Editor, add the `begin` and `end` columns with a default value of the `timespan`.
[image: dco]

Now add a Script Component Transformation (SCT), and add the Input Columns of `timespan, begin, end` and mark `begin, end` as `ReadWrite`.
[image: sct cols]

Still inside the SCT, click on Script in the left hand pane, then click `Edit Script` at the bottom of the dialog.  This will launch a Visual Studio instance to edit your C# script.

Scroll down to the `Input0_ProcessInputRow` function and make it look like the following:

```
 public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    var times = Row.timespan.Split(new string[] { " - " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    if (times.Length > 1)
    {
        Row.begin = times[0];
        Row.end = times[1];
    }   
}
```

Save the file, exit that instance of VS (It will be title VstaProjects), then click OK to exit the Script Transformation Editor.

Your dataflow should now look like this.
[image]

Now if you add a data viewer at the bottom of that pipeline, you will see the results you are looking for.

[image: data viewer]

Comment: I can't thank you enough sorrell. This works absolutely perfect! I had some glitch with precompiled binaries of the script but i was able to figure it out!

Answer (score 1):

Check for the presence of a hyphen character in the timespan column.   If there is none, then use the same value for both `begin` and `end`.